# How to Delete from DB when Choose value from dropdownlist and click button

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" 
         DataTextField="number" DataValueField="number"
         AutoPostBack="True"
         DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="delete" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Bank databaseConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [number] FROM [Account]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

c#

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=FATIMAH;Initial Catalog=Bank database;Integrated Security=True");
    String sql;
    sql = "delete FROM Account where number ='" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue +"'";
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
     conn.Close();
    }

}
```

‬‏

Comment: A command needs to be executed to do anything. In your code there is no _comm.ExecuteNonQuery();_ also,before executing the command, the connection needs to be opened (_conn.Open()_)

Comment: Go take a look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Why are you surrounding your `number` value in quotes? If the field is in fact an `integer` in the DB you'll be having issues. You also never execute your command

Comment: @MartinBrown you could argue that's irrelevant here as it's values from a dropdown, but still a valuable topic to understand nonetheless

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre is the ASP.Net Dropdown List control clever enough to validate the data passed to it in the HTTP Request? Personally I wouldn't want to rely on that. Also we can't see what the Number column of the Account table contains. It may be a dirty source.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Button click code is wrong, this would be a post back so it should be (and as @nad mentioned you also need to execute the actual command)

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=FATIMAH;Initial Catalog=Bank database;Integrated Security=True");
    String sql;
    sql = "delete FROM Account where number ='" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue +"'";
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery() 
    conn.Close();
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` is a _must_ to delete the record.

Answer (score 0):

As steve mentioned you need to use `comm.ExecuteNonQuery()` and need to open the connection

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=FATIMAH;Initial Catalog=Bank database;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                var sql = "delete FROM Account where number ='" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue + "'";
                using (var comm = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `ExecuteNonQuery` method to actually delete the record.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=FATIMAH;Initial Catalog=Bank database;Integrated Security=True");
    String sql;
    sql = "delete FROM Account where number ='" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue +"'";
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery() 
    conn.Close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with the code.

First the Button1_Click event is probably only going to get fired on a Post Back, but the if statement only runs if it isn't a post back. I'd just lose the condition completely, but you could simply remove the `!` (not).

Second you never actually open the connection or execute the command once it is created. It needs to call conn.Open and one of the comm.Execute... methods to actually do anything.

Also there is a possible security (SQL Injection) issue with the concatenation of the value into the query. The correct way is to pass the variable as a parameter to the command. It may stop your system becoming the subject of headline news one day.

Finally there is the possibility of a connection leak as the conn variable is not assigned in a using statement and the conn.Close() call is not in a finally block. The comm variable should probably be disposed as well.

Try this instead:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=FATIMAH;Initial Catalog=Bank database;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            string sql = "delete Account where number = @number";
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", DropDownList3.SelectedValue);
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```